# Why would I configure the /etc/networks file?

Tags: networking, freebsd

I'm playing with a FreeBSD VM. I'm more accustomed to Linux, which doesn't need /etc/networks as far as I'm aware.

[Nik Clayton's FreeBSD Network Administrators Guide](https://people.freebsd.org/%7Enik/nag/book.html#x-087-2-iface.simple-resolv) says this about the /etc/networks file:

"Just as with a host's IP address, you should sometimes use a symbolic name for network numbers, too. Therefore, the hosts file has a companion called /etc/networks that maps network names to network numbers, and vice versa."

It goes on to give an example of use, but it doesn't explain when or why the /etc/networks file would ever be used.

I notice "man 5 networks" at the [FreeBSD website](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=networks&sektion=5) mentions DARPA, which suggests it's a very old file format. The [Linux edition](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/networks.5.html) mentions netstat and route, which are still used on FreeBSD. This suggests there might be some sort of dynamic routing use for /etc/networks the same way we use /etc/hosts in combination with DNS?

Is there a purpose to /etc/networks? Or is it just a legacy artifact of old FreeBSD versions that hasn't been removed yet?

Comment: The same `/etc/networks` file is present on Linux. But yes, it looks obsolete; network classes have been deprecated since the early 1990s. As this is more of a history question, I've voted to migrate this question to our sister site [unix.se].

Comment: I would suggest that it's a legacy from the old [classful network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classful_network) addressing architecture.

Comment: If it helps, I also vote to migrate the question. Good call, sir.